# How to write data in file in specific format with FileOutputStream and PrintWriter

Tags: java

I have class Artical:

first variable is code of artical, second variable is name of article and third is price of article.

```
public class Artical {
    private final String codeOfArtical;
    private final String nameOfArtical;
    private double priceOfArtical;

    public Artical(String codeOfArtical, String nameOfArtical, double priceOfArtical) {
        this.codeOfArtical= codeOfArtical;
        this.nameOfArtical= nameOfArtical;
        this.priceOfArtical= priceOfArtical;
    }
   public void setPriceOfArtical(double priceOfArtical) {
        this.priceOfArtical= priceOfArtical;
    }

    public String getCodeOfArtical() {
        return codeOfArtical;
    }

    public String getNameOfArtical() {
        return nameOfArtical;
    }

    public double getPriceOfArtical() {
        return priceOfArtical;
    }
            
}
```

I want in main class to write something like:

```
Artical a1 = new Artical("841740102156", "LG Monitor", 600.00);
new ShowArticalClass(a1).do();
new WriteArticalInFileClass(new File("baza.csv"), a1).do();
```

so that data in file will be written in format like this:

```
841740102156; Monitor LG; 600.00;

914918414989; Intel CPU; 250.00;
```

- Those 2 classes ShowArticalClass and WriteArticalInFileClass arent important, those are abstract classes.*

So my question is: How do I set **format** to look like this, where every line is new Artical.

Comment: Using a `FileOutputStream` and a `FileWriter`? A specific format is not an inherent aspect of those classes. **You** need to call the appropriate methods, with the appropriate arguments, in the appropriate order. For every article, you'd print the code, then a semicolon, then the name, then another semicolon, then the price, then another semicolon, and finally a newline character. You can modify that algorithm to add spaces after a semicolon and, based on your example output, an extra newline character between articles.

Comment: However, if you want to use a common format, such as JSON, XML, CSV, and so on, then there is likely a library out there that can handle converting POJOs into the appropriate output for you (and vice versa). Note your format is essentially a CSV file but using semicolons as the delimiter instead of commas.

Comment: Are you looking for `+`? If `something` is an `Artical`, `something.getCodeOfArtical()+"; "+something.getNameOfArtical()+"; "+something.getPriceOfArtical()` will create such line for you.

Answer (score 0):

A very naive implementation can be the following:

1. Create a class that in turn creates a `CSVWriter` (assuming you want to write to a CSV). That class will expose a public method allowing you to pass in a path where the desired csv file lives as well as the `Artical` object you want to write to this file. Using that class you will format your data and write them to the file. An example of this could be:

```java
public class CsvWriter {

    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    private static CsvWriter writer;

    private CsvWriter() {}

    public static CsvWriter getInstance() {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            if (null == writer) {
                writer = new CsvWriter();
            }
            return writer;
        }
    }

    public void writeCsv(String filePath, Artical content) throws IOException {
        try (var writer = createWriter(filePath)) {
            writer.append(getDataline(content)).append("\n");
        }
    }

    private String getDataline(Artical content) {
        return String.join(",", content.getCode(), content.getName(), Double.toString(content.getPrice()));
    }

    private PrintWriter createWriter(String stringPath) throws IOException {
        var path = Paths.get(stringPath);
        try {
            if (Files.exists(path)) {
                System.out.printf("File under path %s exists. Will append to it%n", stringPath);
                return new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(path.toFile(), true));
            }
            return new PrintWriter(path.toFile());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error has occurred while writing to a file");
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

Note that this will take into account where the file provided is already in place (thus appending to it). In any other case the file will be created and written to directly.

1. Call this write method in a fashion similar to this:

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    var artical = new Artical("1", "Test", 10.10);
    CsvWriter.getInstance().writeCsv("/tmp/test1.csv", artical);
    var artical2 = new Artical("2", "Test", 11.14);
    CsvWriter.getInstance().writeCsv("/tmp/test1.csv", artical2);
}
```

With that as a starting point you can go ahead and modify the code to be able to handle list of `Artical` objects.

If you really need to support CSV files though I would strongly recommend into looking at the various CSV related libraries that are out there instead of implementing your own code.